# Making Check Boxes Check When I Open my Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am making a windows form in VB and i need the Check Boxes in a Checklist box checked by default any idea how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add an item:

```
CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("This is checked", True)
```

or loop through your list:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
  CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, True)
Next
```